# error: view didn't return HttpResponse object in generic class based views using mixin in Django?

Tags: django, mixins, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I am writing a `mixin` that would enable for partial saving of `form`. For more details on this, please see my [previous post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774412/attributeerror-myview-has-no-attribute-object-in-custom-mixin-in-django). while that is fixed, I have another error. I think the error comes from `post method` of mixing for not returnig `HttpResponse Object`. I am doing a `super` call which should take care of that. But that didn't work.

**Error:**

```
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    The view blog.views.ArticleCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

Here is the **mixin:**

```
class PendFormMixin(object):
    form_hash_name = 'form_hash'
    pend_button_name = 'pend'
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """
        Returns a dictionary of arguments to pass into the form instantiation.
        If resuming a pended form, this will retrieve data from the database.
        """
        form_hash = self.kwargs.get(self.form_hash_name)
        print "form_hash", form_hash
        if form_hash:
            import_path = self.get_import_path(self.get_form_class())
            return {'data': self.get_pended_data(import_path, form_hash)}
        else:
            print "called"
            # print super(PendFormMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()
            return super(PendFormMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests with form data. If the form was pended, it doesn't follow
        the normal flow, but saves the values for later instead.
        """
        self.object = None
        if self.pend_button_name in self.request.POST:
            print "here"
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            print form_class
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            # print "form is ", form
            self.form_pended(form)
            super(PendFormMixin, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            super(PendFormMixin, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

# Custom methods follow
    def get_import_path(self, form_class):
        return '{0}.{1}'.format(form_class.__module__, form_class.__name__)

    def get_form_hash(self, form):
        content = ','.join('{0}:{1}'.format(n, form.data[n]) for n in form.fields.keys())
        return md5(content).hexdigest()

    def form_pended(self, form):
        import_path = self.get_import_path(self.get_form_class())
        form_hash = self.get_form_hash(form)
        print "in form_pended"
        pended_form = PendedForm.objects.get_or_create(form_class=import_path,
                                                       hash=form_hash)
        print "form_class", import_path
        print "form_hash", form_hash
        print "pended_form", pended_form
        for name in form.fields.keys():
            pended_form[0].data.get_or_create(name=name, value=form.data[name])
        print pended_form[0]
        return form_hash

    def get_pended_data(self, import_path, form_hash):
        data = PendedValue.objects.filter(import_path=import_path, form_hash=form_hash)
        return dict((d.name, d.value) for d in data)
```

Here is the **View:**

```
class ArticleCreateView(PendFormMixin, CreateView):
      form_class = ArticleForm
      model = Article
      template_name = "article_create.html"
      success_url = '/admin'

      def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        If the request is ajax, save the form and return a json response.
        Otherwise return super as expected.
        """
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            self.object = form.save()
            time.sleep(5)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps("success"),
                mimetype="application/json")
        return super(ArticleCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

      def form_invalid(self, form):
        """
        We haz errors in the form. If ajax, return them as json.
        Otherwise, proceed as normal.
        """
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(json.dumps(form.errors),
                mimetype="application/json")
        return super(ArticleCreateView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post` method of a Class-Based View should return a `HttpResponse` object (as the exception says, obviously). In your mixin, you forgot to return something, hence the error. You just need to return the result from `CreateView`, from your `super()` call:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles POST requests with form data. If the form was pended, it doesn't follow
    the normal flow, but saves the values for later instead.
    """
    self.object = None
    if self.pend_button_name in self.request.POST:
        # You do things there

    # It is the same line, you don't need an else block then. Note the "return"
    return super(PendFormMixin, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. but I have other issues which I posted here. can you help out please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794670/post-method-in-generic-class-based-view-is-not-called-upon-form-submission-in-dj

Answer (score 1):

Calling super() does not make your method return anything, it only calls the superclass. You should use return super(...) in your PendFormMixin.post() method.